# WSL2 "This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer."

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I restarted my computer and installed updates.
Now I cannot login to WSL2 Ubuntu20.04 LTS
Error:

```
CORP+myUserName ~
$ wsl.exe
This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer.

CORP+myUserName ~
$ wsl.exe -e bash --norc
This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer.

CORP+myUserName ~
$ wsl.exe --user myUserName
This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer.
```

How do I get WSL2 to stop causing bugs all the time?

Comment: Hello. There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.

Comment: This really appears to be a Windows question not an Ubuntu one - see for example [WSL: This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1622533/wsl-this-user-isnt-allowed-to-sign-in-to-this-computer)

Comment: it's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: I assume that `wsl ~ -u root` gives you the same message, right?

Answer (score 1):

If this was a WSL1 instance that has recently been upgraded to WSL2, you will need to do these things:

1. Clear the security event log
   <sup>Event Viewer ⇢ Windows Logs ⇢ Security</sup>
2. Open the Registry Editor (`regedit`)
3. Search for the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\CrashOnAuditFail` key and set its value to `1`
4. Reboot

From here, WSL2 should complain less.

Comment: No dice, tried this elsewhere

Comment: Are there any other things that you’ve tried that are not recorded in the question? Typing this stuff out on a tablet is a right pain, and I’d hate to continue misusing your time and mine 

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer for you, but enough thoughts and things to try that they won't fit in comments:

- From [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5678), it appears the problem, at least in that case, was related to the Virtual Machine Platform (a subset of Hyper-V designed to run WSL2).
- To see if you can isolate it, trying installing a distribution as WSL1 and see if it launches:

  First, set the *default* version of WSL with:

  ```
  wsl --set-default-version 1
  ```

  Then install a different Ubuntu than the one you currently have installed in the Microsoft Store.  For instance, if you have "Ubuntu" (no version) currently installed, then install "Ubuntu 20.04".  Or vice-versa.

  If the configuration stage (where you set the username/password) executes, then WSL1 is running.  Then we know the problem is isolated to WSL2.
- If WSL1 is working, then try to disable/re-enable the Virtual Machine Platform feature in Windows.  It sounds like the ownership may have changed.  Perhaps the corporate update scripts?:

  - Disable *"Virtual Machine Platform"* under *"Turn Windows feature on or off"*
  - Restart Windows
  - Enable the VMP again
  - Reboot

  I'm hoping that takes care of it, but if not ...
- Try the same with the Windows Subsystem for Linux feature itself, but especially if WSL1 doesn't work.
- Uninstall (in *Apps and Features*) the "Windows Subsystem for Linux Update" (the kernel package), reboot, and then [reinstall it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package)
- In Windows Services, check the *"Hyper-V Host Compute Service" -- It should be set to run as *"Local System"* (as most other services).  If not, that could be the issue.
- Check the Event Viewer for any other hints